# Nodejs MySQL pool connection advice to many companies databases

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have an web app that wil be accessed by multiples companies.

I use, in my backend, a node API accessing MySQL databases with  mysql2 lib.

Each company has your owner database.

I have an account database to save info about each company and which is your database name.

On backend, I use node express and a middleware to identify each company by your URL. With the url I can query the account database and I get the correct database name to each company.

After that, I can check if the company has a connection pool. Otherwise, I create or not a connection pool to the company(this is my doubt).

I have two options to pool:

1. Create a single pool to all companies and change the database before  acquire a db connection using mysql "changeUser" method.
2. Create a pool to each company and there is no need to use "changeUser"

For now, I have 5 companies, but this amount will increase at soon.

What option pool will be better to future when  I have more companies accessing the app?

Comment: The MySQL Admin can set the connection limit for any of the users accessing the machine. If you want more companies accessing the app, you will need to consider scaling horizontally.

Comment: @BGPHiJACK Thank you. But for performance reasons, which option will be better? A single pool or many?

Comment: Depends on your architecture, there's no right or wrong answer. You could run two pools connecting to different databases where one has a connectionLimit and the other doesn't. There's many reasons why you may new two or more pools opened.